# NSMutableArray's objects not calling dealloc method after removeAllObjects

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to get the dealloc method to run on some items that are/were stored in a mutable array, but can't seem to find a way to make it happen.

I ran into this problem while working in a larger ARC project and found an answer in this post: [dealloc method is not invoked when set an object to nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174860/dealloc-method-is-not-invoked-when-set-an-object-to-nil). After reading that answer I felt I understood how ARC should be handling the code in question (below), however after running it in a very simple test project I get the same results.

In the main view controller I init a mutable array (a strong property) and add some other view controllers to it. I then remove all objects:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    containerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        //item +1 (item at +1)
        Item *item = [[Item alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        //item +1 (item at +2)
        [containerArray addObject:item];

        //ARC should release item -1 (item at +1...I think)
    }

    //removeAllObjects should release each item -1 (item(s) at 0)
    [containerArray removeAllObjects];
    //dealloc should be called...
}
```

In the Item view controller:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"item dealloc");
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your code 3 times, I could not see any flaws in your approach. I thought everything was right, and that `dealloc` should be called 10 times when you remove all the objects from the array.

Then I decided to try the code, and I just discovered that.... we both were right :) the code is perfect. When I run it I get the *item dealloc* output 10 times.

- Are your really sure you are trying it in a `ARC` project?
- Is the `dealloc` inside the `Item` class?

There is some other thing you are not doing right, but the code and the arguments are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am running this in a small ARC project and the dealloc method is inside the Item class. The code in question is the only code added to a default project (after adding the main and Item view controller classes). I'm using Xcode 4.2, running on a ios 5.0 simulator. Don't know if that matters here. I'll take another go at it to see if there's something else obvious I missed, given that it runs correctly for you.  Also, if you don't mind, what are those other things I'm not doing right (I'm still very much learning my way around obj-c and ios).

Comment: I meant it has to be something else, but I cannot think of anything right now. The only thing I can do is share the project where I tried the code. Download the zip file and see if it works: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26398429/so_answer.zip

Comment: Your project is running correctly for me too. Thanks for this, I just need to look through yours and mine to see what I did differently. I'll comment again when I find it. Thanks again.

Comment: Apparently in my haste, my simple project wasn't adding a root view controller for the window. Once I did that, all the items were calling dealloc. The problem now (which probably needs another question if I can't figure it out) is in my large project, modifying the item in any way inside the loop prevents dealloc. Just creating it, adding it, and removing it works though. Modifying the object in the simple project works fine...

Comment: Found my real problem. My item class was adding itself as a delegate for another one of my custom classes. That delegate property was mistakenly set as strong, so once the item was created, the other class retained it.

Comment: That's what I meant by saying it should be something else, but it was difficult to say without seeing the entire code. I'm glad you could find your problem.